# define and use a discrete probability density function in c++

Tags: c++, math, random, distribution, probability-density

I want to define a specific probability density function (pdf) for n numbers at C++ and then pick some of them later in my code.

my pdf is : P (x) = (1/logn) * f(x)^(-2)

f(x) has a deterministic number that is already determined for each x earlier in my code.

I prefer to use standard library function, since I should use my program in a computer cluster that using additional libraries such as boost more likely produces further issues in that cluster.

my initial code that I have found is:

```
  for(int x=1;x<n+1;x++){
    // I calculate all f(x) and therefore P(x) here
  }
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution { .. not sure how to use P(x)s here .. };

  int prob[n]={};

  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    int number = distribution(generator);
    ++prob[number];
  }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, the possible numbers are 1 to n ? Or is this just an example?

Comment: sorry for delay. yes they are 1 to n. this is my actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now construct vector with weights:

```
std::vector< double> weights( n);
for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  weights[i] = pdf( i + 1);
}

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution( weights.begin(), weights.end()) ;

int prob[n]={};

for ( int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
  int number = distribution( generator);
  ++prob[number];
}
```

This will generate starting from 0, this is how discrete_distribution works, but you can assume with no loss of correctness that values are calculated for a range `1, ..., n` (weights are calculated for `1, ..., n`).

[example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c9005a4cc0ed9d6)

Comment: I lost the idea that by having this pdf ready, how could I pick a number from 1 to n based on this pdf and assign it to for example j?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: that is a very introductory question actually, but Im confused. I mean, at the end how could I generate one instance from i=1 to n based on this distribution and say: int j = the generated value.

Comment: int number = distribution( generator); will generate a number in range [0,...,n-1] for you, and you know how this number corresponds to your original domain. If I get this right from what you mentioned your domain is X=(1,...,n), so your mapping is f(n)=n+1=distribution( generator) + 1. Example: if you got 2 from a call to  distribution( generator) than your number is 3.

Comment: Strangely, I got a error c2661 in using two arguments for discrete_distribution ( weights.begin(), weights.end()), which apparently should not use two arguments.

Comment: it can, look at 2nd constructor [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) which is template< class InputIt >
discrete_distribution( InputIt first, InputIt last ); So what is the text of error message?

Comment: Error 5 error C2661: 'std::discrete_distribution<_Ty>::discrete_distribution' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Comment: IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::discrete_distribution<_Ty>::discrete_distribution [with _Ty=int]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>)

Comment: I am using vc++ 12, apparantly there is a bug there and I did not try the newst uodate for VC++ (update 4) it may fix this problem